# How to scrape data from flexbox element with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a data from a website by using scrapy with python. Even though the data is shown on the page and no error is thrown, the xpath code I'm using (see below) returns just an empty list.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector 

url = "https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/tassi-e-valute/valute/contro-euro/cambio/EURUS.FX"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
sel = Selector(text = text)

value = sel.xpath('//div[@class="col-3"]//span[@class="fmw-value"]//text()').extract()
value
```

How can I retrieve this data?

Comment: disable java-script by pressing Ctrl+shift+p in the developer tool. see if the website is showing the value that you want to extract, if not you have to use selenium or splash to get this data from this website or you can try to find an API.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the content is dynamically created after the webpage is loaded, meaning the content you see when visiting the webpage after all the content is loaded will be different than what `requests.get` will "see" when making the request.

As an example:

running the following xpath query: `'//div[@class="fmw-head-data-preview"]'` on the data from `requests.get`:

```py
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

url = "https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/tassi-e-valute/valute/contro-euro/cambio/EURUS.FX"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
sel = Selector(text = text)
value = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fmw-head-data-preview"]').extract()
print(value)
```

yields:

```
['<div class="col-md-6"> <div class="skeleton-group"> <span class="skeleton-block skeleton-block--dark skeleton-block--big"></span> <span class="skeleton-block"></span> </div></div>', '<div class="col-md-6"> <div class="skeleton-group"> <span class="skeleton-block skeleton-block--dark skeleton-block--mid"></span> <span...
```

notice all the `skeleton-group` classes.

While the equivalent loaded front-facing website html looks like this:

```html
<div class="fmw-head-data-preview">
    <span class="fmw-value fmw-value--huge">1.0869</span> 
    <span class="fmw-label">Ultimo</span>
</div>
```

Digging around using the [networking dev tool](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) of chrome I found this endpoint: "https://vwd-proxy.ilsole24ore.com/FinanzaMercati/WidgetSelector/header-dettaglio?topicName=EURUS.FX" which returns the data I think you are looking for.

I also suspect that they have an API-endpoint somewhere so do some digging with a networking tool and try to reverse-engineer what you find.

Hope this was of help!